# How to list all available backup dates using duplicity

Tags: duplicity

Using duplicity to backup a folder on a certain event, how can I get a list of all available backup dates as I don't know in advance when the event occurred?
I want to list the available dates as deja-dup does. Final goal is to restore a certain date from the list.

```
duplicity file:///backup-folder restore-folder --restore-time "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Comment: Even better... You can get a list of commands and options at [`duplicity(1)` man page](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The following command is probably what you're looking for:

```
duplicity collection-status file:///backup-folder
```

example:

```
Found primary backup chain with matching signature chain:
-------------------------
Chain start time: Mon Mar  4 10:37:27 2013
Chain end time: Fri Mar 15 15:42:22 2013
Number of contained backup sets: 3
Total number of contained volumes: 10
 Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
                Full         Mon Mar  4 10:37:27 2013                 8
         Incremental         Fri Mar  8 15:53:07 2013                 1
         Incremental         Fri Mar 15 15:42:22 2013                 1
-------------------------
No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.
```

Comment: Does it take a long time to execute the command? I am running it now since 5 minutes without any output

Comment: Mine took just some seconds

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I believe you can do (using S3 as an example):

`duplicity list-current-files s3+http://bucket/folder`

Hope this helps somewhat...or hope that you already found your answer!